# How can I collect the sum of different columns while filtering?

Tags: google-sheets

I am creating a travel budget spreadsheet and need to be able to sum different filters (By Month, By Salesperson, By State, etc)...is there a way for me to display the sum of a column based on what is displayed in variable filters?

---

I believe I solved this. I ended up just pulling each person's travel into a different sheet on a new document and having multiple tabs (one for each staff member). Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a pivot table (select A:O, Data > Pivot table report... and add fields of your choice).

Maybe `Primary Attendee` in **Rows**, `Month` in **Columns**, `Fee` in **Values** and `State` in **Filter** - but the options are almost limitless (that's the power of a pivot table).

Comment: Looks like this might work!! Thank you so much!!!